# Can anyone tell me what is the name of this UI component?

Tags: android, user-interface

[What is the name of it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO1da.png)

I want to display a notification with 'something' like that after I touch a button. I wonder that is a 'Ticker', but actually not.

Here's my code:

```
public void createNotification(View view) {
    final int mId = 1;

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")\
            .setTicker("Blah")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");               
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

The code work perfectly. I've try to run this project on JellyBean and everything works as I wanted (the ticker appear), but on Kitkat and Lollipop it just display an icon, nothing else.

[Notificationdemo on works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMqK8.png)

I thought this is a snackbar on top, but its not. Is it Head's Up Notification? Help me.

Sorry for bad english. Please check my code, I'm beginner on Android.

Answer (score 0):

It is called Head's Up Notification or just floating notification. It is mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#metadata) in the documentation.

> setPriority() causes notifications with the priority field set to PRIORITY_MAX or PRIORITY_HIGH to appear in a small floating window if the notification also has sound or vibration.

And

> With Android 5.0 (API level 21), notifications can appear in a small floating window (also called a heads-up notification) when the device is active (that is, the device is unlocked and its screen is on).

It is also mentioned that the notification has to have a ringtone or vibration set in order to appear as floating. If you don't want vibration or sound, try a little hack `notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);` this way you (hopefully) won't even need vibration permission.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have modified my code but nothing's happen

Comment: @DiazHarizky In what way exactly?